# Angular 4 Update observable via http.get

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-observables

I'm trying to update an observable which is returned in html from an API call.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with this.

The html (on another component)

```
<common-content [theme]="theme" ></common-content>
```

and the component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { ThemeModel } from '../../models';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'common-content',
  template: `<div innerHTML = "{{innerHtml}}"></div>`
})

export class CommonContentComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() page: string;
    @Input() theme: ThemeModel;
    innerHtml: string;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.populatePage();
    }

    populatePage(){
        let thisUrl = 'myPage.html';
        this.http.get(thisUrl).subscribe(f => {
            var content = <string>f['_body'];
            this.innerHtml = content.replace("{{theme.Name}}", this.theme.name);
            }, (error) => {
                let e = error;
            }, () => {
        });
    }
}
```

so instead of doing a "replace" the observable should just update automatically.

I've tried to use a subscribe and I also tried a promise, however I don't seem to be able to get the syntax to behave.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show the contents of f

Comment: just a chip in, instead of `<string> f['_body'];` change to `<string>f.text()` safer

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve. Your code sends an HTTP request, and when the response comes back, initializes the innerHtml field of your component with the body of the response (after some replacement). What else would you like to achieve?

Comment: use <div [innerHTML]="innerHtml"></div> in template instead of <div innerHTML = "{{innerHtml}}"></div>

Comment: Thanks Theophilus, I've used f.text() instead. What I'm trying to achieve Chandru is to not need to do a replace on the returned html. It returns it as a string instead of as a usable observable.

Answer (score 1):

1)  What you want to achieve is not clear.
What I can make out is on success you want to update the dom.
2) Dont use inner html for that and use interpolation or ngModel for the same with a sanitizer.
3) Another approach would be to create a custom reusable directive for the same.

An approach could be:

1) Make a pipe for sanitization:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
/**
 *
 * @export
 * @class SafeHtmlPipe
 * @implements {PipeTransform}
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   *
   * @param {DomSanitizer} sanitizer
   * @memberof SafeHtmlPipe
   */
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  /**
   *
   * @param {any} style
   * @returns
   * @memberof SafeHtmlPipe
   */
  transform(style) {
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see docs
  }
}
```

2) Use it like :

```
<div class="card_description" [innerHTML]="scenarioStepDataDesc | safeHtml"></div>
```

where scenarioStepDataDesc is your HTML content.

3) Use a shared module for pipes and other reusable components/directives

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';
import { BlockUIModule } from 'ng-block-ui';
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from './components/autoComplete/autoComplete.component';
import { DialogDataComponent } from './components/dialog/dialog.component';
import { SafeHtmlPipe } from './pipes/safeHtml.pipe';
/**
 *
 * @export
 * @class SharedModule
 */
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, MaterialModule, BlockUIModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BlockUIModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AutoCompleteComponent,
    DialogDataComponent,
    SafeHtmlPipe
  ],
  declarations: [AutoCompleteComponent, DialogDataComponent, SafeHtmlPipe]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hi Shubhendu, I've tried to write a service, but I can't seem to get it to work either.

Comment: please define the problem statement again as it is not clear, then i will try to help.

Comment: Sure, the problem is that I load some html from another page. I'd like the interpolation to work on the html that I just loaded so I can see the interpolated result in the view rather than the plain text. In other words I'm seeing {{ theme.name }} in the view, but what I want to see in the view is the data configured in the theme configuration file which could be "Yellow Theme" instead.

Comment: I've never used plnkr before, but I've put most of the code (not working) in http://plnkr.co/edit/X2jYniwfVs0SK7WQPMm7  .  Nothing I've tried has actually worked so far

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you update your `<string> f['_body'];` change to `<string>f.text()`, and also `innerHTML = "{{innerHtml}}"` to `[innerHTML]="view"`   anyway check the below plnkr link as it's doing exactly what you are trying to perform

```
this._http.get(link).subscribe(f => {
     this.loading = false;
            var content = <string>f.text();
            this.view = content.replace("{{theme.Name}}", this.theme.name);
            }, (error) => {
              this.loading = false;
              console.error(error);
                alert(error);
            });
```

the template is like this

```
content <button (click)="open('external.html')">Open Page</button>
      <strong *ngIf="loading">LOADING...</strong>
      <div [innerHTML]="view"></div>
```

the `external.html` is simple as below

```
me playing around with this theme with name 
<b>
  {{theme.Name}}
</b>
```

here is the running [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LrWNvP?p=preview)

But for String interpolation processing as if the content was in the same template as the parent loading it and bind `this` to the template scope, which is similar to angular 1 **ng-include** check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065289/5836034) as it helps in solving that (instead of re doing it), and note this is for **angular 4** and above

> using Angular 4.0.0-beta.6's [ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgComponentOutlet-directive.html).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Theophilus, unfortunately when I use "[innerHTML]="view"   " as you describe above I get {{theme.Name}} on the view instead of the data, so I still need to pretend I'm doing the interpolation using a "replace" command whereas I'd prefer that the observable handle the replacement as it does normally. So instead of seeing {{theme.Name}} I'd like to see "Yellow Theme" (or whatever I put in the config file).

Comment: check the plnkr link, it replaces it, or you are trying to make angular take the loaded innerHTML content to work as the way `ng-include` works?

Comment: yes. The idea is that I have multiple themes. I have some files that are common among those themes. So I want to load in components without loading a common theme, because I want to use the originating theme and not change it.

Comment: I had a look at the plunkr code, it still has "this.view = content.replace("{{theme.Name}}", this.theme.name);"  which is the line of code I want to remove, but still have it look the same as what you have in the plunkr

Comment: In other words, both your code and my code work, but with magic strings. I'd prefer not to have magic strings in the code. It's for a big project, so if I can get this one page working I can refactor the whole solution.

Comment: updating the answer to help you solve this, with reference too @Mick

Comment: Thanks, I tried using a pipe, but that didn't do the interpolation either. So it seems the problem is with interpolation not working, and trapping it with Middleware doesn't seem to achieve that.

Comment: checkout my answer, i added the possible way by using **ngComponentOutlet.**